# Rendering Vector Tiles Mapbox GL

Tags: node.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js, vector-tiles

I want to use Mapbox GL to render vector tiles that I am generating from PostGIS requests. I have built a tile server using Mapnik, sphericalmecator, and pg plugins for npm. I added the tile endpoint to the stylesheet for Mapbox GL, and have confirmed that the correct tiles are requested, but the tiles are not rendered on the map. I used the same backend for a leaflet plugin and it works correctly, so I'm not sure I have to change the backend. Any advice is appreciated. Code is below.

This is the index.html file that I am loading.

```
  var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'outdoors-v7.json',
    center: [47.4333, 19.2500],
    zoom: 9
  });
  map.on('style.load', function() {
    map.addSource("parcelLayer", {
      "type": "vector",
      "tiles": ["http://localhost:5001/data/city/lots/budapest/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"],
    });

    map.addLayer({
      "id": "parcelLayer",
      "type": "fill",
      "source": "parcelLayer",
      "layout": {
        "visibility": "visible"
      },
      "paint": {
        "fill-color": '#ff0000',
        "fill-opacity": 1
      }
    });
});
```

This is the routes that the map is calling.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var conString = require('../../database').conString;
var pg = require('pg');
var SphericalMercator = require('sphericalmercator');
var mapnik = require('mapnik');
var zlib = require('zlib');

mapnik.register_default_fonts();
mapnik.register_default_input_plugins();

var mercator = new SphericalMercator({
  size: 256
 });

router.get('/:city_name/:z/:x/:y.pbf', function(req, res) {

  var city_name = req.params.city_name;
  var bbox = mercator.bbox(
    +req.params.x,
    +req.params.y,
    +req.params.z,
    false,
    '4326'
  );

  pg.connect(conString, function(err, client, done){
    var config_object = {
      'medellin' : {
         'attributes': ['cobama', 'subtipo_lote', 'tipo_lote', 'estrato', 'zona', 'usopredial', 'npisos', 'calificacion']
       },
      'lima' : {
         'attributes': ['objectid', 'id_lote', 'tip_uso', 'id_dist', 'estado']
      },
      'budapest': {
         'attributes': ['id', 'tags']
      }
    };
    var handleError = function(err) {
      // no error occurred, continue with the request
      if(!err) return false;
      // An error occurred, remove the client from the connection pool.
      // A truthy value passed to done will remove the connection from the pool
      // instead of simply returning it to be reused.
      // In this case, if we have successfully received a client (truthy)
      // then it will be removed from the pool.
      if(client){
        done(client);
      }
      console.log(err);
      // res.writeHead(500, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
      // res.end('An error occurred');
      return true;
    };
    // handle an error from the connection
    if(handleError(err)) return;
    if(city_name === 'medellin' || city_name === 'lima' || city_name === 'budapest'){
      client.query('SELECT row_to_json(fc) FROM ( SELECT "FeatureCollection" As type, array_to_json(array_agg(f)) As features FROM (SELECT 'Feature' As type, ST_AsGeoJSON(lg.wkb_geometry)::json As geometry, row_to_json((SELECT l FROM (SELECT ' + config_object[city_name]['attributes'].join(', ') + ' ) As l )) As properties FROM ' + city_name + '_parcels As lg WHERE st_intersects(lg.wkb_geometry, st_makeenvelope(' + bbox.toString() + ', 4326) ) ) As f )  As fc', function(err, result){
        if (err) {
          console.log('error in the query');
          return console.error('error running query', err);
        }
        // handle an error from the connection
        if(handleError(err)) return;
        var vtile = new mapnik.VectorTile(+req.params.z, +req.params.x, +req.params.y);
        if( (typeof result.rows[0] !== 'undefined')  && (result.rows[0].row_to_json.features !== null )){
          try {
            vtile.addGeoJSON(JSON.stringify(result.rows[0].row_to_json), 'lots');
            console.log(result.rows[0].row_to_json.features[0]);
          } catch (e) {
            console.log('came back with an error');
            console.log(e);
          }
        }
        res.setHeader('Content-Encoding', 'deflate');
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-protobuf');
        zlib.deflate(vtile.getData(), function(err, pbf) {
          done();
          // res.writeHead(200);
          res.send(pbf);
        });    
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Please ask any other questions you might have.

Comment: So the .pbf files and the style JSON are definitely making it into the browser ok? Do you have another way to verify that the .pbf files are correctly generated? Can you load your vector tile source into Mapbox Studio Classic?

Comment: Yeah I can call the route and I get a pbf that has embedded data in it. 

I used the same backend with this https://github.com/SpatialServer/Leaflet.MapboxVectorTile and it worked some I'm wondering why it wouldn't render for MapboxGL.

Unfortunately Mapbox Studio Classic only impelements the TileJSON spec so I would have to create a new JSON for the tiles to be called. I tried this but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: You might have to step through the MapboxGL code to see where it's going wrong. Maybe it's rendering in the wrong place, maybe it's invisible, maybe the style ends up with nothing rendered, maybe the whole layer is invisible for some reason...

Comment: This post is quite old, however I think that the issue is the name you are using on Mapbox (ie "parcelLayer"). The tile is generated with 'lots' name. That may be the issue. Try to fix it.